# Why is this calculation in C# returning a zero value for iCalcExample?

Tags: c#

I replaced the variables with values and the code work and sections of this work independently. Here is the section of code in question and it is the iCalcExample calculation I'm trying to correct.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(args.ProposedValue) > 0) {
        // pending CommAmt_c
        string sCommAmt_c = (string) edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["CommAmt_c"].ToString();
        int iCommAmt_c = Convert.ToInt32(edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["CommAmt_c"]);
        // OrderDtl.DocExtPriceDtl
        string sExtPrice = (string) edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["DocExtPriceDtl"].ToString();
        int iExtPrice = Convert.ToInt32(edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["DocExtPriceDtl"]);
        // OrderDtl.DocDiscount
        string sDocDisc = (string) edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["DocDiscount"].ToString();
        int iDocDisc = Convert.ToInt32(edvOrderDtl.dataView[edvOrderDtl.Row]["DocDiscount"]);
        // Calculated value
        int iCalcExample = Convert.ToInt32((iCommAmt_c) / (iExtPrice - iDocDisc)) * 100;
        // string sCalcExample = iCalcExample.ToString();
        // string sCalcExample = String.Format("{0:F?}", iCalcExample, 2);
        int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2;
        string formatString = String.Concat("{0:F", numberOfDecimalPlaces, "}");
        string sCalcExample = string.Format(formatString, iCalcExample);

        // end variables
        MessageBox.Show("ExtPrice: " + sExtPrice);
        MessageBox.Show("DocDisc: " + sDocDisc);
        MessageBox.Show("Calc Example: " + sCalcExample);

    }
```

Comment: What are the values used in the calculation?  I bet that iCommAmt_c/(iExtPrice - iDocDisc) is less than 1.00 and gets truncated to 0.  Multiply by 100 first rather than after.

Comment: (15000 / (150000 - 200)) * 100. It does come out to less then 1 (0.10) before multiplying by 100.

Comment: Or based on the notation they are integers and integer math is used

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this: 100*(iCommAmt_c/(iExtPrice - iDocDisc)) and it still returned a zero value. I'm thinking instead of converting to int I should be converting to decimal.

Comment: Hi pinkfloydx33, thanks for your suggestion. It looks like that addressed the same problem. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you both! I changed the code to int iCalcExample = (Convert.ToInt32(iCommAmt_c)*100) / (iExtPrice - iDocDisc); and it is now working properly.